# AWS Elasticache Redis Geo Query with Bounding Polygon

Tags: amazon-web-services, redis, geospatial, geo, amazon-elasticache

I read that AWS Elasticache Redis does not allow us to install modules onto Redis. It seems to say so on the official AWS Documentation.

My question is, what is the best way to perform a geospatial search with a bounding polygon?

Consider I am able to do this

```
GEOADD dataPoints 100.0 1.0 ptA 100.1 0.9 ptB 100.8 1.2 ptC
```

And I have a boundary

```
GEOADD boundary 90.0 0.5 corner1 90.0 1.0 corner2 101.0 0.5 corner3 101.0 1.0 corner4
```

And of course the above examples are just simplified versions of the lat-lng, and dataPoints can be a huge set. How can I achieve this function of 'intersecting' the dataPoints and boundary?

Comment: You can do something like what I did in this Lua lib, but it ain't gonna be too performant: https://github.com/RedisLabs/geo.lua

Comment: @ItamarHaber , i have tried loading the script and using it. After being able to load it, i am not able to understand how to use the commands. I also am not able to see any documentation or examples. Can you provide an example? Thank you.